# Removing _class attribute from MongoDb attribute Spring Java (Different predicament)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

So firstly I have Googled/research other solutions but they do not work for my problem.

```
public class BasicRule {

  public BasicRule() {
  }

  @Id
  private String id;

  @Field("fname")
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
  private int fname;

  @Field("sname")
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
  private int sname;

  @Field("gender")
  @SerializedName("gender")
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
  private int gender;

  //getter setter

  public BasicRule(String id, int fname, int sname, int gender) {
    this.id = id;
    this.fname = fname;
    this.sname = sname;
    this.gender = gender;
}
```

This is the data I want to insert into the database. It does this correctly however

```
  "_class" : "BasicRule"
```

is always included.

I used MongoRepository which has a save method which directly saves the MongoDb.

```
public void saveBasicRules(List<BasicRule> basicRuleList) {
    basicRuleRepository.save(basicRuleList);
}
```

I tried the solution

```
public @Bean
MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
   return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new Mongo(), "database");
}

public @Bean
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
   //remove _class
   MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(
       mongoDbFactory(), new MongoMappingContext());
   converter.setTypeMapper(new DefaultMongoTypeMapper(null));

   MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory(), converter);

   return mongoTemplate;
}
```

I tried adding the above in the BasicRule class but it did not help. Any advice please?

Comment: how are you storing data in mongodb? are you autowiring mongoTemplate?